# What is the difference between building OpenCV4 from source and pip install opencv-python?

Tags: python, opencv, pip

I have tried both the ways to install OpenCV, while building from source there were many errors so I tried the

> pip install opencv-python

method. Everything works fine but I still don't know what is the difference between the two as building from source takes so much time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is if you build from source, then you can enable or disable some functionalities, for example, you can build OpenCV with [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) module, Or you can build OpenCV with [Deep-Learning-Inference-Engine-backend](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/Intel%27s-Deep-Learning-Inference-Engine-backend), Or `CUDA`, Or [Qt](https://www.qt.io/), Or with [GStreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/), Or with [tesseract-ocr](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/)
 and many other configurations which you can change or enable/disable. But if you do not need the extra functionality, then you can directly install the pre-built library and use it.

Comment: Thankyou for such a great insight. Cleared a lot of confusion